# QListWidget row size with a custom QListWidgetItem

Tags: android, c++, qt, qtwidgets

Using Qt Designer, I created an `Item` class inheriting from `QWidget`, and added a few widgtes.
Then, again using Qt Designer, I created a `MainWindow` from `QMainWindow`, and added a `QListWidget` object called `list`, and a `QPushButton` called `pushButton`.

On `MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)`, I added to the default code:

> ui->list->setSizeAdjustPolicy(QListWidget::AdjustToContents);

On void `MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()`, I wrote:

> Item *my_item = new Item(this);
>
> QListWidgetItem * item = new ListWidgetItem();
>
> item->setSizeHint(QSize(0, 400));
>
> ui->list->addItem(item);
>
> ui->list->setItemWidget(item, my_item );

Testing on the Linux Ubuntu running on my notebook, it all goes well, but when I run on my Android Moto G4 cell phone, the `Item` objects inserted in `list` are never displayed correctly. Using 400 in `setSizeHint` makes the widgets to be displayed, but cut at the bottom. Using, say, 100, makes the widgets to be squeezed, impossible to read.

Does anyone have any idea on how to make it work?

Thanks!!